# ColdFusion 2016 (WS-Security Implementation)

Tags: xml, web-services, coldfusion

I am trying to connect to a service that uses WS-Security (username + password) in order to secure itself. I am connecting from ColdFusion 2016.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<cfxml variable="securityHeaders">
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-65" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">1vrSoBRiARpSIXvhXExgqg==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2017-07-07T20:07:22.041Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</cfxml>

<cfscript>
    ws = createObject("webservice", #wsurl#,{wsversion="2",refreshWSDL=true});
    WriteDump(#securityHeaders#);
    AddSoapRequestHeader(ws, "","",#securityHeaders#,true);

    version = ws.GetVersion();
</cfscript>
```

However, it seems that ColdFusion does not like something about my XML. I am receiving this error:

```
 An error occurred while Parsing an XML document.
The prefix "soapenv" for attribute "soapenv:mustUnderstand" associated with an element type "wsse:Security" is not bound.

The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/test/getVersion.cfm: line 12

10 : </cfif>
11 : 
12 : <cfxml variable="securityHeaders">
13 :     <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
14 :    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-65" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
```

If i remove the soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" then I receive a different error but my understanding is that it needs to be there. Is there something I am doing wrong in this XML? Is there a reason it does not know about soapenv:mustUnderstand?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated - Thanks all for your time.

**EDIT 1**
This change fixed the issue:

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

But now I am receiving the following:

```
 Cannot perform web service invocation GetVersion.
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:

AxisFault

 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}MustUnderstand

 faultSubcode: 

 faultString: Did not understand &quot;MustUnderstand&quot; header(s):

 faultActor: 

 faultNode: 

 faultDetail: 

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:

    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:96)

    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)

    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2765)

    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2748)

    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2424)

    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2347)

    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1804)
```

This is a working envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:abc="ABCService" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" 
   xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
   xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-41D8D78B82FF48D24D149946784898124">
   <wsse:Username>usernamegoeshere</wsse:Username>
   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">passgoeshere</wsse:Password>
   <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">noncehere</wsse:Nonce>
   <wsu:Created>2017-07-07T22:50:48.980Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <abc:GetVersion/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is a failing envelope that I can see from the trace (im not sure if CF2016 / Axis is choking on the Request or Result)

```
<MessageHeaders>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:actor="">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-65" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>
<!-- Removed-->
</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>
<!-- Removed-->
</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>
<!-- Removed-->
</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2017-07-07T20:35:22.041Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
<To d4p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://pc/Service/Service.svc</To>
<Action d4p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">Service/Service/GetVersion</Action>
</MessageHeaders>
```

In my traces - I can see that it "receives message over a channel, security protocol verified the message, message is read, I see the GetVersion execution To/from and then I see an outgoing message. Is it possible that axis is failing on the receive of the message?

Comment: Is there a test end point #wsurl# we can try to test against?

Comment: Unfortunately not, all hosted locally. @ah7866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it came down to the way that WCF and Coldfusion interact. In this case, the request was hitting the server and Axis was failing to understand the response.

In SOAPUI the response had a Timestamp header/tag set to mustunderstand. This header gets added in WCF when using the basichttpbinding. The client could not understand this header and therefore would choke.

The solution was to move to a customBinding in order to set the includeTimestamp to false on the security node.

**Binding Config**

```
<bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="myCustomBinding">
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false">
            <secureConversationBootstrap/>
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport></httpsTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

**Service Config**:

```
  <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="MyNamespace.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="myCustomBinding"
          bindingNamespace="MyNamespace" contract="MyNameSpace.IMyService" />
```

The response then looks like this (notice no timestamp tag):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <s:Body>
      <GetVersionResponse xmlns="MyNamespace">
         <GetVersionResult>1.0</GetVersionResult>
      </GetVersionResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And my coldfusion code looks like this:

```
<cfxml variable="securityHeaders" casesensitive="true">
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-65" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username>usernamegoeshere</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">passgoeshere</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">1vrSoBRiARpSIXvhXExgqg==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2017-07-07T20:35:22.041Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</cfxml>

<cfscript>
    ws = createObject("webservice", #wsurl#);
    //WriteDump(#securityHeaders#);
    AddSoapRequestHeader(ws, "dummy","dummy",#securityHeaders#,true);
    version = ws.GetVersion();
    WriteOutput(version);
</cfscript>
```